# How do I set my own unique validator in mongoose involving an array of ids?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to develop a program that organizes questions and subquestions in a database and recommends questions to a front-end user. Currently, my problem is that I want to make each question have a list of subquestions ids that is an empty array by default ([]). However, I am also setting a unique validator that checks if any two lists of subquestions are the same or not.

Here is how I believe the mongoose validator is validating questions and subquestions (the following code block is pseudo code):

```
Q1 = {
----attributes----
subquestions = [1,2,3]
}

Q2 = {
--attributes 
subquestions = [1,2,3]
}

return !Q1.subquestions.equals(Q2.subquestions);
```

The above code block would be repeated in a manner for all questions.

Now, here is the code I have for my Question schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Subquestion = require('./Subquestion');
const getSubcategory = require('../utils/getSubcategory');

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    -------other attributes-------------
    subquestions: getSubcategory(Subquestion)
});

const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);

module.exports = Question;
```

And here is my code for the getSubcategory function:

```
---code defining getWeightValidator----
function getSubcategory(Model) {
    return {
        type: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: Model.modelName,
            unique: true //Second important line
        }],
        default: [],
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: getWeightValidator(Model),
            message: props => `The weight sum of ${props.value} exceeds 100 or is less than 0`
        },
        unique: true        // Most Important line
    }
}

module.exports = getSubcategory;
```

Here, my main problem is that I want to check for a way to change the unique validation at "Most Important Line". I want to make a unique validator that is completely the same except for a slight change. If the array is empty, do not check for its uniqueness. I want to check this because I don't want an error being given due to two questions having empty arrays which technically are the same:
`[].equals([]) //true`

Due to this validator, I get the following error message when I try to insert some fake data:

`E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.questions index: subquestions_1 dup key: { subquestions: undefined }`

This is where I would need help the most. How do I make this slight exception in my unique validator?

What I tried was to make my own validator that checks for uniqueness of all subquestions arrays in the Question model. My first thought of the solution was to reference Question inside validator. Here is how I modified getSubcateogry :

```
function getSubcategory(Model, Parent) {
    return {
        type: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: Model.modelName,
            unique: true
        }],
        default: [],
        required: true,
        validate: [{
            validator: getWeightValidator(Model),
            message: props => `The weight sum of ${props.value} exceeds 100 or is less than 0`
        }, {
            validator: async function (v) {
                const parents = await Parent.find({});
                const listOfSubcategories = parents.map(parent => parent.subquestions);
                listOfSubcategories.contains(v);
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Here, an additional validator is created that checks all subcategories of the parent Model (in this case Question) and checks if this list of subcategories inserted is already in the total listOfSubcategories. However, this method didn't work because I cannot reference a model before it is created. What do I specifically mean by that? In order to explain this, it's better to look at the updated questionSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Subquestion = require('./Subquestion');
const getSubcategory = require('../utils/getSubcategory');

const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ------other attributes------
    subquestions: getSubCategory(Subquestion, Question) // Question undefined 
});

const Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);

module.exports = Question;
```

Here, Question is used before its declaration. Thus, this error came. I didn't have enough time to try other ways to face this issue but I am free to discuss this subject and would be very grateful for anyone putting the time to help me.